# dealing with modal content and SEO

Tags: javascript

Hello and sorry for my bad grammer, English is not my main language :(

example scenario:

HTML Example

```
<a class="href-preventer" href="website.com/permalink/">Post Title</a>
```

Javascript Example

```
document.querySelectorAll(".href-preventer").forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState('data', 'Post Title', '/permalink/');
    ... 
    -- open HTML modal -
  });
});
```

As you can see I'm preventing `<a>` tag to disable page full load, changing current's page URL and showing the content in a modal.

I wonder, google bots will be still crawling and following my links in `<a>` tag?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap and bots don't click on links, they parse them out of the page's rendered HTML

Comment: thank you for your answer, so my links still will be crawled right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if you don't want your link to be crawled you can add some limitations to access your link it's not the effective way but it's will stopping robots activities if they are just parse the code
- you can add some fields to your link which will be generated from your server for user cookies for example
  `website.com/permalink/?id=13566&access_token=12455`
- so when the user open your website you can use cookies to send request to your server by ajax to create an id and access_token for this cookies so when this user click on the link they are added and the user will access the link by this id, access_token else you can redirect him to another thing or return warning message but that's if you control the link i mean if it's on your server else you can create just div's and when they clicked you can move user to the page by `location.href` or load the links by js or ajax after the page loaded so when they Scraping your website they won't find any links..
- That's what i can suggest and i hope this helps you